# information extraction mac

Tags: macos

Would it be possible to extract the following information from logs?

- Start up/Shut down times of Mac.
- Connected volumes to Mac.

Also, would it be possible to retrieve the information like -

- all the devices connected till now to Mac, for example - all USB device, printers etc.,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract info about sessions, reboots and shutdowns using the command `last`.
As far as I know, a log isn't kept of all the connected devices, but I could be wrong on this one.